# Selecting a cell in a active row and display in vba

Tags: vba, select

I need to select few cells in the row of the active cell and display them in the email.

I got the following on the internet but this is returing `True` on result.

```
With ActiveCell
Range(Cells(.Row, "B"), Cells(.Row, "D")).Select
End With
```

I have the emailing code working fine but the selection is not working quite well.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an example of how your code might preferably be written, and I have no idea what is contained in those cells...

```
Dim emailTo As String
Dim emailSubject As String
Dim emailBody As String
'# ...
With ActiveCell
    emailTo = Cells(.Row, "B").Value
    emailSubject = Cells(.Row, "C").Value
    emailBody = Cells(.Row, "D").Value
End With
'# ...
Call SendEmail(emailTo, emailSubject, emailBody)
```

Comment: Thanks Agnes. Didn't know it was that simple.